# Differentiating between two notions of being a complete set of sentences in some first-order language

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, model-theory

Let $L$ be a first order language and let $S$ be a set of $L$-sentences. I have seen two definitions of what it means for $S$ to be complete:

1. $S$ is complete iff for every $L$-sentence $A$, either $A\in S$ or $\neg A\in S$ (e.g. in Peter G. Hinman's *Fundamentals of Mathematical Logic*)
2. $S$ is complete iff for every $L$-sentence $A$, either $S\vDash A$ or $S\vDash\neg A$ (e.g. in David marker's *Model Theory: An Introduction*).

Notion 1 seems to be more common, and it implies notion 2. I have two questions:

**Is there a standard reason why 1 appears to be more common?**

**When would we want to work with a set of sentences in some language that verifies 2 but not 1? Is there an example you may want to mention as particularly interesting?**

Edit: I can think of the following reason why we may prefer one over the other.

Lemma: A satisfiable, consistent set $S$ of $L$-sentences is *complete* iff any two structures satisfying $S$ are elementary equivalent.

This lemma, as stated is true if complete is defined as in 2. However, if complete is defined as in 1, then $S$ needs to be in addition, closed under $\vDash$, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: A set of $L$-sentences $S$ is *complete* iff its deductive closure $T$ is complete in sense 1. — for every $L$-sentence $A$, either $A\in T$ or $\neg A\in T$.

Comment: Definition 1 should be used only when $S$ is closed under logical consequence, i.e., when $S$ is a theory as defined in Hinman's book. (I strongly suspect that, although Hinman states the definition in general, he uses it only for theories.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I would add the requirement that $S$ is consistent.)

The reason 2) is more common is that it does not assume S to be closed under logical consequences. E.g. the set containing the sentences that axiomatize the dense linear orders is a complete theory with respect to 2) but not with respect to 1).